# Mocked Angular navigateByUrl still running page reload

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write a test for a button click which triggers a navigateByUrl function call with some params.

I have mocked Router and provided to the testing module as such

```
let mockRouter = {
navigateByUrl: jasmine.createSpy("navigateByUrl").and.callFake(() => {
  console.log("fake is called");
}),
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [RecoverPasswordComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

when i click the button and navigateByUrl is triggered, i am getting the console as written but i am also getting a error as `Some of your tests did a full page reload!` which means that actual navigateByUrl is triggered.

I am not able to get an idea of, if the function is spied than why the actual function call is triggered?

Comment: Do you see `fake is called`? And show the code of your component, maybe you have a window.location.href or something of that sort.

Comment: @AliF50 yes i saw the `fake is called` but i found the error and posted it as well!
Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally figured out what was causing this!
So basically i had a form in which my button was stated, as the form was not binded with ng-submit callback so on clicking the button the default event for a form button was triggered which reloaded the test suite.